# Font problems in memoir chapter

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class to write a thesis, and find the `veelo` chapter style well enough. However, its chapter title is in times roman, and it does not have subsection counting.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\chapterstyle{veelo}
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}

\end{document}
```

Therefore, I want to do the following changes:

(1) Replace the chapter default font with the sans font (the problem is that I could only change the section and subsection titles into sans font, but could not change the chapter title (counter and name) into the sans font);

(2) Add the subsection counting.

Is there anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks very much.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks very much. One more question. Why the number "1" in the chapter counter looks different from "1.1" and "1.1.1" although they are all defined by \sffamily? Is it possible to change the chapter counter to be consistent? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There are three macros that set the font for elements of the chapter:

  - String "`Chapter`": `\chapnamefont`
  - Chapter number: `\chapnumfont`
  - Chapter title: `\chaptitlefont`

  The following example appends `\sffamily` to these font macros using `\g@addto@macro`. This way, there is no need to know, what font settings the macros also contain (font size, ...).
- Numbering of the subsections can be achieved by:

  ```
  \setsecnumdepth{subsection}
  ```

Full example file:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\chapterstyle{veelo}
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}   
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\chapnamefont{\sffamily} 
\g@addto@macro\chapnumfont{\sffamily}  
\g@addto@macro\chaptitlefont{\sffamily}
\makeatother

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\section{Section Name}
\subsection{Subsection Name}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Chapter number

The chapter number has two differences:

- It is scaled by a large factor, the height of the number is resized to `18mm` by chapter style `veela`.
- The chapter number is not bold in opposite to the section numbers.

The following example shows the effect of the scaling:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\noindent
\normalsize 1
\large 1
\Large 1
\LARGE 1
\huge 1
\Huge 1
\HUGE 1
\fontsize{12mm}{12mm}\selectfont 1
\fontsize{15mm}{15mm}\selectfont 1
\fontsize{18mm}{18mm}\selectfont 1
\fontsize{21mm}{21mm}\selectfont 1
\fontsize{24mm}{24mm}\selectfont 1
\fontsize{27mm}{27mm}\selectfont 1

\end{document}
```

> [image: Digit one scaled]

Comment: Thanks very much. One more question. Why the number "1" in the chapter counter looks different from "1.1" and "1.1.1" although they are all defined by \sffamily? Is it possible to change the chapter counter to be consistent? Thanks